# How to analyse u as s evolves across different values?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, dynamical-systems, biology

For part **(d)** of the following question should I look at the integrated version of the equation in part **(a)** in order to look at how $u$ evolves i.e. take limits of $s$ or does it make sense to just look at the equation in part **(a)** i.e. the change in $u$ with respect to $\tau$.

Also, is taking the limit of $s$ the right path to follow? If not what is the right way to solve this question?

Any help would be really appreciated!

[image]

Comment: This is essentially a bifurcation question asking about the behavior of $u$ across a range of $s$ value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part (d), when the activating signal is $0$ (e.g. $s= 0$), then the ode takes the form:
\begin{equation}
\frac{du}{d\tau}  = - ru + \frac{u^2}{1+u^2}
\end{equation}
Note that since $u(0) = 0$, this means $\frac{du}{d\tau} = 0$, so $u(\tau) = 0$ for all $\tau$ given $s = 0$.

Now, the question wants to slowly increase $s$, so $s>0$. At some earlier time, then we can approximate $u \approx 0$ giving:
\begin{equation}
\frac{du}{d\tau}  \approx s > 0
\end{equation}
This implies $u(\tau) > 0$ at least for some time after $s>0$. Next, the question wants to know if $u(\tau)$ **reverts** back to $0$ once the activating signal is gone, e.g. $s \rightarrow 0$. Note that this gives us back:
\begin{equation}
\frac{du}{d\tau}  = - ru + \frac{u^2}{1+u^2}
\end{equation}
**However**, this time $u(\text{initial}) = u(\text{immediately after signal is gone}) > 0$. This times, you will need to find the stability of the equilibrium $u^* = 0$. To do this, we differentiate $f(u) = -ru + \frac{u^2}{1+ u^2}$ to obtain:
\begin{equation}
f'(u) = -r + \frac{2u}{1+u^2}
\end{equation}
At equilibrium then, $f'(u^*) = -r$, hence $u^*$ is locally asymptotically stable. This means $u$ would still go back to $0$ once the activating signal is gone.